# Adding column value as suffix to specific dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

working on a dictionary of multiple dataframes.
Need to run a function which adds suffix to columns in the dataframe and suffix being values of one of the column.

My INPUT:

```
list1=['november','december']
list2=[january,'february']
```

dictionary which looks like this:

```
key   type       size       value        
df1   dataframe  (101,10)   [col1,col2,november,december,january,february,years]
df2   dataframe  (102,10)   [col1,col2,november,december,january,february,years]
```

each dataframe looks like:
df1

```
col1 col2 november december january february years        
1111  abc    1       2       3          4    1718
2222  def    5       6       7          8    1718
3333  ghi    9       10      11         12   1718
4444  jkl    13      14      15         16   1718
```

df2

```
col1 col2 november december january february years        
1111  abc    1       2       3          4    1819
2222  def    5       6       7          8    1819
3333  ghi    9       10      11         12   1819
4444  jkl    13      14      15         16   1819
```

my desired output is:
df1

```
col1 col2 november_17 december_17 january_18 february_18    years        
1111  abc    1             2        3          4            1718
2222  def    5             6        7          8            1718
3333  ghi    9             10       11         12           1718
4444  jkl    13            14       15         16           1718
```

df2

```
col1 col2 november_18 december_18 january_19 february_19    years        
1111  abc    1       2       3          4                   1819
2222  def    5       6       7          8                   1819
3333  ghi    9       10      11         12                  1819
4444  jkl    13      14      15         16                  1819
```

which then get joined into a single dataframe:

```
col1 col2  november_17 december_17 january_18  february_18  november_18 december_18 january_19 february_19           
1111  abc      1             2          3          4           1           2            3          4             
2222  def      5             6          7          8           5           6            7          8                 
3333  ghi      9             10         11         12          9           10           11         12                 
4444  jkl      13            14         15         16          13          14           15         16
```

Currently I have written the below code but I am unable to add suffix to my months columns:

```
calender1=['november','december']
calender2=['january','february']

#creating two sets for my loop

columns_to_suffix = set(calender1)
columns_to_suffix2 = set(calender1)

#building empty dictionary to put dataframes result

df_dict = {}
for key, df in df_list.items():
        df.columns = [f"{c}+'_'+ {df.year.astype(str)}" if c in columns_to_suffix else c for c in df.columns]
        df_dict[key] = df
```

f"{c}+ {df.year.astype(str)}" is not working for me as "f"{c}+_x" does. and I am clueless on how to merge all the dictionary element dataframes into a single one. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the column renaming, where the two digits are appended. It looks like it increase for months in the following year, but what is the initial one (for november and december) based on? You do have a "year" column, where those numbers appear again, but this time as an apparent four-digit year. Which makes it very confusing: are those four-digit not a year, and supposedly to be split into two parts: one for november/december and one for jan/feb? Or should we look at the century part, use that for nov/dev, then increase that by one for jan/feb?

Comment: Looking at your code, it makes less sense: `f"{c}+ {df.year.astype(str)}"` misses the underscore for starters, and the value appended, `df.year.astype(str)` is a four digit string, not two digits.

Comment: Also, `df.year.astype(str)` returns a *full* year column converted to strings; not a single value. That's probably the error you are seeing.

Comment: @9769953
a.you are correct year doesnt signifies a year but a period where november/december belong to different year and january february to another (1718 is made from 2017 and 2018), I have edited the column name hoping that it doesnt confuse people further.b).yes, I am sorry I had missed that too and I have edited accordingly.c)yes I am getting a long string and it is I guess the whole column but I am unable to write the correct code to solve it. kindly help